# How do I make a collection dissapear and reappear?

Tags: keyframes, visibility

In my animation, I want the destructable object to replace the non destructable clone right before the impact frame, but I cant seem to keyframe the renderability of the collection, any way to fix this or to make a collection dissapear and reappear?